# ng container doesn't update after suscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually i have one ng container like that :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="leftColumn">
[...]
</ng container>
<ng-container *ngIf="rightColumn">
[...]
</ng container>
```

In my ts i have a subscribe for change the boolean.

```
this.myservice.getStatus(statusCol => {
this.leftColumn = statusCol.left
this.rightColumn = statusCol.right
});
```

The boolean is updated but the ng container stay hidden. I try with changedetectorref too. Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the method that change both values is called ?

Comment: Yes i use a debugger and when i next my value the method is called @Elikill58 The value is updated but the ng container stay hidden

Comment: What is the value of `statusCol.left` and `statusCol.right`? Are they truthy? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Comment: @noamyg Yes they are, the problem is the dom i think the value is really updated. I don't have the same problem with "div". But i need a ng container

Comment: try using `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`

Comment: If you copied your examples, it could be a syntactic error in the closing tag. Try to fix it by putting the `-` between `ng` and `container` in the closing tags.

Comment: @TroudiGhaith [hidden] doesn't exist on ng container

Comment: @EduMüller No i don't copy it was just an example :)

Comment: Is CommonModule imported in the Module declaring your component?

Comment: This is really a bug, I've also encountered with this issue, and haven't been able to find a solution which works with ng-container. Use span or div for a workaround.